# Is this a correct way to factorise the symmetric group?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations, symmetric-groups

Let $S_k$ be the set of permutations of $(1,...,k)$ and $S(\overline{1,l}),S(\overline{l+1,k}),S(l,k-l) \subset S_k$ be the following subsets
\begin{align}
S(\overline{1,l}) &= \{ \sigma \in S_k\ |\ \sigma(l+1) = l+1,...,\sigma k=k\} \\
S(\overline{l+1,k}) &= \{ \sigma \in S_k\ |\ \sigma(1) = 1,...,\sigma l=l\}
\end{align}
and
$$
S(l,k-l) = \{\sigma \in S_k\ |\ \sigma:(1,...,k) \mapsto (i_1,...,i_l,j_1,...,j_{k-l}),\\i_1<...<i_l \land j_1<...<j_{k-l}\}
$$
Then any $\sigma \in S_k$ can be written as $\sigma = \pi\kappa\rho$ with $\kappa\in S(\overline{1,l}),\rho \in S(\overline{l+1,k})$ and $\pi \in S(l,k-l)$, and therefore $S(l,k-l) \times S(\overline{1,l}) \times S(\overline{l+1,k}) \cong S_k$ under $(\pi,\kappa,\rho) \mapsto \pi\kappa\rho$.

> A different way to achieve the same idea is $\sigma = \pi_{\kappa,\rho}$, where $\kappa \in S_l, \rho \in S_{k-l}$ and (as above) $\pi \in S(l,k-l)$, where
> $$
> \pi_{\kappa,\rho}:(1,\dots,k) \mapsto (i_{\kappa1},\dots,i_{\kappa l},j_{\rho 1},\dots,j_{\rho(k-l)})
> $$
> and therefore $S(l,k-l) \times S_l \times S_{k-l} \cong S_k$ under $(\pi,\kappa,\rho) \mapsto \pi_{\kappa,\rho}$.

**Question I:** Is this valid (both ways) ? and if it is the case, where can I find a reference with proof ?

**Question II:** Is it possible to generalise this (written here in the second way) such that one factors the same group as $S_k = S(k_1,\dots,k_r)\times S_{k_1}\times,...,\times S_{k_r}$, where $\sum_j k_j = k$ in such a way that any element $S_k \ni \sigma = \pi_{\kappa_1,\dots,\kappa_r}$, where $\pi \in S(k_1,\dots,k_r)$ i.e.
\begin{align}
\pi:(1,...,k) &\mapsto (i^{(1)}_1,...,i^{(1)}_{k_1},...,i^{(r)}_1,...,i^{(r)}_{k_r}),& &\begin{cases}
i^{(1)}_1<...<i^{(1)}_{k_1},\\
...,\\
i^{(r)}_1<...<i^{(r)}_{k_r}
\end{cases}
\end{align}
and $\kappa_j \in S_{k_j}$ and
$$
\pi_{\kappa_1,\dots,\kappa_r}:(1,...,k) \mapsto (i^{(1)}_{\kappa_1 1},...,i^{(1)}_{\kappa_1 k_1},...,i^{(r)}_{\kappa_r 1},...,i^{(r)}_{\kappa_r k_r})
$$
?

(necessary but not sufficient test) If we test the cardinatlities we get $|S_k|=k!$, and
\begin{align}
|S_l|&=l!, & |S_{k-l}|& =(k-l)! & |S(l,k-l)|& =\frac{k!}{l!(k-l)!}
\end{align}
where the product $|S(l,k-l) \times S_l \times S_{k-l}| = k! =|S_k|$.

---

Added:

The idea is that one considers the combination $(l,k-l)$, i.e. divide $(1,...,k)$ into two disjoint sets (one has $l$ element) disregarding the order within the single set, consider a shuffle if you like, and then arrange these two sets by $S(\overline{1,l})$ and $S(\overline{l+1,k})$ to get $\sigma$. An argument that may complete the test into a proof is to show that these proucts $\pi\kappa\rho$ are *distinct* for *different* triples and so the map
\begin{align}
A:& S(l,k-l) \times S(\overline{1,l}) \times S(\overline{l+1,k}) \to S_k, &
(\pi,\kappa,\rho) &\mapsto \pi\kappa\rho
\end{align}
is a bijection.

Comment: See related topic: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1072534/proof-of-the-fact-that-the-set-of-p-q-shuffles-is-a-cross-section-of-the-subgr

Comment: @FallenApart , in your post I think it should be "or" not "and" for the definition of $\sigma \in S_p\times S_q$

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Proof of the fact that the set of (p,q) shuffles is a cross section of the subgroup $S_p\times S_q$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1072534/proof-of-the-fact-that-the-set-of-p-q-shuffles-is-a-cross-section-of-the-subgr)

Comment: BTW the notation in the suggested post has also the bad notation (corrected in my post) that causes the same confusion. $S_p, S_q$ and $S_n$, where $n = p+q$, so what is $S_p$ if $p=q$ ? the one that fixes the first $p$ elements or permutes only these ?